# Pass a string array to an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm unable to pass an array of strings through an HTTP get to my action. My HTTP GET does this:

http://www.example.com/Add?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4

My code looks like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add(params string[] id) 
{ 
    // I expect this:
        // id = string[]{"1","2","3","4"}

    // I get this: 
        // id always comes in as {string[1]}... aka. string array with one element
        // id[0] is "" - aka. the first element is always an empty string
}
```

The possible ways my HTTP Get could come in:

1. `http://www.example.com/Add?id=1`
2. `http://www.example.com/Add?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4`
3. `http://www.example.com/Add/1`

How do I handle this in one controller method?

Other things I've tried:

- Overload the method (you cannot overload controller methods)
- Pass in the ids as a comma separated string, which worked, but is hacky

Comment: Remove the `params` keyword

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tried that. It breaks in the case that the GET comes in as `http://www.example.com/Add/1`

Comment: You would need a different method for that one assuming you are using the default routing (which would expect the parameter to be `int id` (or `string id`) - not an array)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, I was not totally clear about my ids they will also have letters. I used numbers to simplify the question a little

Comment: Whether its `int` or `string` does not really matter :) There may be a way to do this with a custom route and 2 parameters in the method (e.g. `(string[] id, string xx)` where the first 2 urls will bind to `id` and the 3rd will bind to `xx` - but then you would need a conditional check in the method

Comment: I got it working with GET request using Ajax and passing the ids the way you want in the URL. Would you be interested in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Request.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784.aspx) collection.

Comment: This does not address OP's 3rd case (where the value is a route value, not a query string value - `Request.QueryString` will be an empty collection)

Comment: Who keep upvoting this? It does NOT answer the question!

Answer (score -1):

This may not answer you question as you may not be interested in jQuery- Ajax solution. But those who might come here searching for an answer, following is the way I achieved it.

**Jquery & Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Method?id=2&id=3',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    success: function(response){},
    error: function(response){}
});
```

**C# Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExportRecords(string[] id)
{
    foreach(string value in  id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(value);
    } 
     return View();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue, and certainly does not address the case where the url is `.../Add/1`

Comment: And `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` is pointless for a GET, and your code throws an exception because of `datatype: "json",` (the method returns html)